# Python: How to split hourly values into 15 minute buckets?

Tags: python, pandas

happy new year to all!

I guess this question might be an easy one, but i can't figure it out.

How can i turn hourly data into 15 minute buckets quickly in python (see table below). Basically the left column should be converted into the right one.Just duplicate the hourly value for times and dump it into a new column.

Thanks for the support!

Cheers!

```css
 Hourly  15mins
1 28.90 1 28.90
2 28.88 1 28.90
3 28.68 1 28.90
4 28.67 1 28.90
5 28.52 2 28.88
6 28.79 2 28.88
7 31.33 2 28.88
8 32.60 2 28.88
9 42.00 3 28.68
10 44.00 3 28.68
11 44.00 3 28.68
12 44.00 3 28.68
13 39.94 4 28.67
14 39.90 4 28.67
15 38.09 4 28.67
16 39.94 4 28.67
17 44.94 5 28.52
18 66.01 5 28.52
19 49.45 5 28.52
20 48.37 5 28.52
21 38.02 6 28.79
22 34.55 6 28.79
23 33.33 6 28.79
24 32.05 6 28.79
  7 31.33
  7 31.33
  7 31.33
  7 31.33
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this through constructing a new DataFrame and using numpy methods.

```
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((np.arange(df.shape[0]).repeat(4, axis=0),
                              np.array(df).repeat(4, axis=0))),
             columns=['hours', '15_minutes'])
```

which returns

```
    hours  15_minutes
0       0       28.90
1       0       28.90
2       0       28.90
3       0       28.90
4       1       28.88
5       1       28.88
       ...
91     22       33.33
92     23       32.05
93     23       32.05
94     23       32.05
95     23       32.05
```

`column_stack` appends arrays by columns (index=0). `np.arange(df.shape[0]).repeat(4, axis=0)` gets the hour IDs by repeating 0 through 23 four times, and the values for each 15 minutes is constructed in a similar manner. `pd.DataFrame` produces the DataFrames and column names are added as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create datetime-like index for your DataFrame, then you can use [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

```
series.resample('15T')
```